# How to get free physical memory of remote computer using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, memory-management, powershell-remoting

I have this:

```
(Get-WMIObject Win32_logicaldisk -computername computer).TotalPhysicalMemory
```

to get size of physical memory installed on remote computer.
How do I get the FREE memory of that computer?

I've tried

```
(Get-WMIObject Win32_logicaldisk -computername computer).FreePhysicalMemory
```

and some other variants, but with no effect. Is there some list of possible "filters"?

Answer (score 14):

Whenever you want to see all of the properties of an object, pipe it to `Format-List *`.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | format-list *
Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | fl *
```

Or if you are looking for a particular propery, you can use wildcard search

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | fl *free*
```

As Aquinas says, you want the `Win32_OperatingSystem` class, `FreePhysicalMemory` property.  `Win32_LogicalDisk` tracks hard disks, not RAM.

Comment: If he actually means diskspace, the properties would be `Size` and `FreeSpace`.

Answer (score 10):

You can also try the `Get-Counter` cmdlet:

```
(Get-Counter -Counter "\Memory\Available MBytes" -ComputerName computer).CounterSamples[0].CookedValue
```

Answer (score 4):

You want `Win32_OperatingSystem` not `Win32_logicaldisk` I believe.

Answer (score 1):

So putting together the other answers:

```
get-ciminstance Win32_OperatingSystem | % FreePhysicalMemory
```

Remotely:

```
invoke-command computer { get-ciminstance Win32_OperatingSystem | % FreePhysicalMemory }
```

Comment: I believe this should really be `Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem`. `Get-WmiObject` was deprecated since PowerShell 3.x and removed since PowerShell 6.x.

Answer (score 1):

Free memory of the local machine (use `-computername foo` for a remote one):

```
(Get-WMIObject Win32_OperatingSystem).FreePhysicalMemory  # in KB

19793740
```

```
(Get-WMIObject Win32_OperatingSystem).FreePhysicalMemory / 1MB  # in GB

18.8592491149902
```

Might seem weird to divide by 1MB to get GB, but the original number is just given in KB. The result is actually no different from writing `* 1KB / 1GB` (which you can also use).

Comment: Thank you for explaining the conversion.